Exploding Gradients when using Momentum!
I'm implementing gradient descent with momentum from scratch in NumPy.
Issue is that I'm receiving exploding gradients after a couple of epochs.
I could apply L2 regularization, which seems to work well, but the fact that this occurs makes me think my implementation of momentum is wrong.
I also found that getting rid of the bias correction term fixes things up as well.
Could anyone check if my implementation is correct?

you can also check the full code on my github, here

def momentum(beta, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, vdw1, vdb1, vdw2, vdb2, epoch):
    eps = 1e-10
    
    vdw1 = (beta * vdw1) + (1 - beta) * dw1
    vdw1 = vdw1 / ( 1 - (beta ** epoch) + eps )

    vdb1 = (beta * vdb1) + (1 - beta) * db1
    vdb1 = vdb1 / ( 1 - (beta ** epoch) + eps)

    vdw2 = (beta * vdw2) + (1 - beta) * dw2
    vdw2 = vdw2 / ( 1 - (beta ** epoch) + eps)

    vdb2 = (beta * vdb2) + (1 - beta) * db2
    vdb2 = vdb2 / ( 1 - (beta ** epoch) + eps)
    return vdw1, vdb1, vdw2, vdb2


def update_momentum(w1, b1, w2, b2, vdw1, vdb1, vdw2, vdb2, alpha):
    w1 = w1 - alpha * vdw1
    b1 = b1 - alpha * vdb1
    w2 = w2 - alpha * vdw2
    b2 = b2 - alpha * vdb2
    return w1, b1, w2, b2
```

